# Javascript python communication

Tags: cefpython

With CEFPython can we create the prototype of a javascript function and build the function in python?

```
<button onclick="somme(b,a)">SOMME</button>
<label id='prompt'>Bonjour</label>

def somme(self,b,a):
    self.ExecuteJavascript(document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "somme ="+b+a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using Javascript bindings, see a snippet here: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/snippets/javascript_bindings.py

Read more about javascript bindings in the Tutorial document.